# Django Rest Patch/Update Functions Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm very new to Python, Django, and the Rest Framework. I'm just trying to set up a simple API to allow data to be updated in a postgresql database. I'm trying to test my patch function but it isn't having any effect in the database. I know the db connection is working since my ViewList endpoints are pulling data correctly. I've searched through many of the similar questions on here but none of them quite matched what I had or the solution provided did not work. Here's what I have currently:

> Model:

```
class Users(models.Model):

    userid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
```

> URL:

```
path('users/<int:userid>/', UsersRudView.as_view(), name='users-rud')
```

> View:

```
class UsersRudView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    lookup_field     = 'userid'
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Users.objects.all()

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

> Here's the call I'm using to test the patch function:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1/'
payload = {"userid":1,"username":"John Smith"}
r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

I've tried a number of different approaches but from what I've seen this should be close to what I need. I just don't know enough about this to know where my error is. I'm hoping it's something very obvious and simple.

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: No, when I run the python script to send the request nothing happens. No errors but no update in the database either.

Comment: You debugged your application?  you see the parameters obtained in the view?

Comment: I tried adding a print to the view in order to check if it was even being triggered but nothing ever printed out.

Comment: what is your response code (ie, value of `r.status_code`) and `r.json()` ?

Comment: Does the GET work ? If it does, see @JerinPeterGeorge 's comment.